# Struggling for passing React routing param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to protect a react route and redirect toward this route when the user has logged in.

Here is my protectedRoute :

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {

   const location = useLocation();

   return auth.getCurrentUser() ? <Outlet /> :
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{from: location}}/>

};
```

And here is my Login component :

```
class LoginForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: { username: "", password: "" },
    errors: {}
  };

  schema = {
    username: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Password")
  };

  doSubmit = () => {

      // Some code for validate login

      const { state } = this.props.location;
      window.location = state ? state.from.pathname : "/";

  };

  render() {
    if (auth.getCurrentUser()) return <Navigate to="/" />;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput("username", "Username")}
          {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
          {this.renderButton("Login")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The program stops at doSubmit function when executing :

```
const { state } = this.props.location;
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: You need to render a <Navigate /> component to change pages. Window.location is not a good way of doing. doSubmit could change the state, which could then render a Navigate component inside the render

Comment: Thanks Trisma, I'll do so for rendering. However, the problem I've mentionned is still there. I don't know how I can get the "from" parameter to redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

In react-router-dom v6 the `Route` components no longer have route props (`history`, `location`, and `match`), and the current solution is to use the React hooks "versions" of these to use within the components being rendered. React hooks can't be used in class components though.

To access the `location` object with a class component you must either convert to a function component, or roll your own custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject the "route props" like the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom` v5.x did.

Also, in v6 the `history` object was replaced by a `navigate` function. This can be accessed via React hook and injected as a prop as well.

## Solution

I won't cover converting a class component to function component. Here's an example custom `withRouter` HOC:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      location={location}
      navigate={navigate}
      // etc...
    />
  );
};
```

And decorate the `LoginForm` component with the new HOC.

```
export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

This will inject a `location` prop for the class component.

```
doSubmit = () => {
  const { location, navigate } = this.props;

  // Some code for validate login

  const { state } = location;

  navigate(state.from || "/", { replace: true });
};
```