# React - Rerender a class component after the window pathname change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Greeting guys, I have an issue with a class component (that handle a list), the first time I mount the component works without any issue showcasing the expected values, unfortunately when I change the pathname while inside the class component it doesn't updated.

```
class Servicelist extends React.Component{
    constructor({path}) {
        super();
        this.path = {path}
        this.state = {
            services : [{
                title : 'Brand & Digital',
                description : `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipiscing elit`,
                image : iservice1,
                details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                cost: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                additional: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                link : '/services/brand_&_digital',
                id : 0
            },
            {
                title : 'Graphic Design',
                description : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipiscing elit',
                image : iservice2,
                details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                cost: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                additional: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                link : '/services/graphic_design',
                id : 1
            },
            {
                title : 'Advertising',
                description : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipiscing elit',
                image : iservice3,
                details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                cost: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                additional: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                link : '/services/advertising',
                id : 2
            },
            {
                title : 'Visual Identity',
                description : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipiscing elit',
                image : iservice4,
                details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                cost: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                additional: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
                link : '/services/visual_identity',
                id : 3
            }]
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.path.path.pathname)
        const service = this.state.services.find(service => service.link === this.path.path.pathname)
        if (service) {
            return <Service {...service} />
        }
        else{
            return null
        }
      }
}
```

This component is been render directly into the app component where I have all my sections

```
function App() {
  const pathname = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/services/:service" element={<Servicelist path={pathname}/>} />
        <Route path="/quote" element={<Quote />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the component `<Servicelist />` its called by links inside the `<Nav/>` component like this...

```
<div className='burgernav-cont'>
            <div className='Home-link'>
                <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='services-links'>
                <Link to="/services/brand_&_digital"> Brand & Digital </Link>
                <Link to="/services/graphic_design"> Graphic Design </Link>
                <Link to="/services/advertising"> Advertising </Link>
                <Link to="/services/visual_identity"> Visual Identity </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='quote-link'>
                <Link to="/quote"> Quote </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='burguer'>
                <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}><Bclose/></button>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you need this component to do when the `location.pathname` changes? I'm inclined to say to create a callback handler for this logic and call it in `componentDidMount` and then conditionally in `componentDidUpdate` based on the prop change. Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: I need ```class Servicelist``` to swap once the ```window.location.pathname``` is updated, right now the way is trigger works the first time but for the obvious reason is already render it wont collect any more data

Comment: Where and how is this `Servicelist` component being rendered? Can you update to share how any routing/navigation is involved?

Comment: The ```<Servicelist />``` component is called as well inside some buttons on the ```<Home />``` component but that works without any issue for the simple reason that once you click one button you are redirect to that service and that's it.

Comment: I see, does this help answer your question for how to access the current route `location` from the class component in RRDv6? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70511614/8690857

Comment: Im one step away, I already send on ```app.js```  the props of ```useLocation()``` inside my class ``` Servicelist ``` and realize the correct service ```const service = this.state.services.find(service => service.link === this.path.path.pathname)``` unfortunately even if the information is render multiple times... its still the same ```pathname```

Comment: Think you could dump your above code into a *running* codesandbox that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick updated. This is the solution at the end I came to.
By reading more about how react route v6 works I get to learn about `useLocation` and how to use the hook inside a class component.

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  const pathname = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/services/:service" element={<Servicelist path={pathname}/>} />
        <Route path="/quote" element={<Quote />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you see it was as simple as passing through the props of `const pathname = useLocation();` to the class component `<Servicelist path={pathname}/>` and learning more of how I can implement this props inside the class component I can fast use the props directly into render (I don't need any more to care about when will rerender thanks to `useLocation` hook)

```js
render() {
        const pathname = this.props.path.pathname
        const service = this.state.services.find(service => service.link === pathname)
        if (service) {
            return <Service {...service} />
        }
        else{
            return null
        }
      }
```

Giving me the expected result whenever I use my navigation bar to swap to another service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React-Router, You can use the useLocation look.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

Pass pathname through Props

```
<Component path={pathname}/>
```

Comment: Its seems like the right answer, but I have another issue, even when I do this ```<Servicelist path={pathname}/>``` it will only pass the first time a pathname, but trying to pass the new pathname will only make the first prop go again

Comment: This should be the main router. i.e. `router.js` or `router/index.js`
This file would be called whenever the URL is changed.  So the `pathname` will reflect the current URL

Comment: `<BrowserRouter>
    <Servicelist path={pathname}/>
 <Routes>
       <Route exact path='/add' element={<NewAccount />} />
       ...
</Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>`

Answer (score 0):

You wanna make a raw router components by yourself?
Ok, That's my:

1. Use `componentDidMount`.
2. Use `ref`.

Here are codes about `kaboom.js` that I used.

```js
  state = {
    canvas: 'canvas',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    kaboom({
      background: [134, 135, 247],
      width: 320,
      height: 240,
      scale: 2,
      canvas: this.refs.canvas as any,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Card>
          {/* @ts-ignore */}
          <canvas width="640" height="640" ref={this.state.canvas}></canvas>
        </Card>
      </>
    )
  }
```

I decide to give you a test codes:

```js
class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        path: 'path',
    }

    lazyRoute = (Component: any) => {
        return (props: any) => <Component {...props} />
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        const service = this.state.services.find(service => service.link === window.location.pathname)


        if (service) {
            
            ReactDom.render(lazyRoute(Service), this.refs.path) 
        }else {
            
            ReactDom.render(<NotFound />, this.refs.path) 
        }
    }

    render() {
        <div ref={this.state.path}></div>
    }
}
```